# Chat replies ending with an apostrophe get messed up in inbox notifications

Tags: bug, chat, notifications, global-inbox, unicode

I noticed this morning that a chat reply, with the last character in the preview being an apostrophe, was messed up.

(; (since it's the TL, it's blacked out) ;)

[image]

I then tested it with a sock of mine:

[image]

In both of these, the last character shown in the preview was `'`. They both did not show correctly.

---

The apostrophe *does* show correctly if it's not the last character:

[image]